# How to convert two arrays to a single JSON object in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have two arrays (that are always going to have the same length). Something like

```bash
array1 = [ "a", "b", "c" ]  
array2 = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to merge both arrays into a single JSON object in C# to something like

```json
{
"a": 1,
"b": 2,
"c": 3
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) + [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0) then json serialization ? (Writing something a little more complete and testing before posting as an answer)

Comment: And please for your next question try to include at least one example of what you have tried to implement [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was that simple: [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) + [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0) before serialization.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var array1 = new string[]{ "a", "b", "c" } ;
var array2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var dict = array1
    .Zip(array2, (a1,a2)=> (key:a1, value:a2))
    .ToDictionary(k => k.key, v => v.value);

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict));
```

[`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) takes two collections of the same size and creates a new one based on the result of a merge function (here, I used it to create tuples)

[`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0) creates an enumerable to a dictionary structure.

Outputs:

```json
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

One note about this answer though: If you have two or more identical items in the first collection, this *WILL* throw an exception.